# Is my IPv6 behind an ISP CGNAT?

Tags: networking, ipv6, isp

I am trying to SSH into my PC from outside my house using its IPv6 address, and I get an error of "host is unreachable".

- test-ipv6.com gives me 10/10 score.
- Pinging my router's IPv6 works.
- Pinging my PC's IPv6 doesn't work.

What's preventing me from accessing remotely?

Comment: Your router’s firewall, of course. Just because there’s no NAT doesn’t mean there’s no stateful packet inspection. What’s your router’s make and model?

Comment: TPLINK Archer A6 v3.0, I have tried disabling the router's firewall (called SPI Firewall in the settings) and still the same result.

Comment: Does your computer show an IPv6 address that exactly matches what's seen by test-ipv6? If the address is the same, it's by definition not behind CGNAT or any other kind of NAT. (Firewalls can easily exist without NAT, though.)

Comment: Is the firmware of your router updated to the latest version?

Comment: yes it does, number by number, exactly the same. Is there a possibility that the PC's firewall itself is the culprit?

Comment: also yes the firmware of the router is the latest version

Comment: Hm, from what I can gather, most TP-Link devices do not have IPv6 firewalling at all. You should replace it if at all possible. It may be your ISP then, blocking all incoming connections. Just ask them.

Comment: i just asked my ISP, they said the IPv6 is "private", and if i want to have it set to public i need to change packages, but from what i can understand, if my IPv6 really is 'private', how is it possible that I can ping my router's IPv6 address but not my PC's?

Comment: @mylo sounds like your ISP set up some device in your internet connection that deliberately makes it worse unless you pay extra money. That, or the support person doesn't know what they're talking about. (Quite possible, since what they said would make sense if it was IPv4)

Comment: the only thing my ISP installed in my house is their own modem, but they said that's been set to 'bridge mode' to allow me to set up the PPPOE connection to them straight from my own router, could it be the their own modem thats blocking the pings? or is it something entirely out of my control?